# Property in object is undefined and clearInterval() not working

Tags: javascript, constructor, setinterval, clearinterval

I have this piece of code:

```
class CombatLog {
constructor(){
    this.idMsg = 0;
    this.timerInterval;
}

startTimer(){
    this.timerInterval = setInterval(this.combatStartLog, 2000);
    $('#combatLog').empty();
}

combatStartLog(){
    console.log(this.idMsg);
    switch (this.idMsg){
        case 3:
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
            $('#combatLog').empty();
            break;
        case 2:
            $('<p>', {
                class: 'combatText',
                id: `${this.idMsg}`
            }).appendTo('#combatLog');
            $(`#${this.idMsg}`).append(`FIGHT!`);
            this.idMsg = 3;
            break;
        case 1:
            $('<p>', {
                class: 'combatText',
                id: `${this.idMsg}`
            }).appendTo('#combatLog');
            $(`#${this.idMsg}`).append(`Prepare your potions...`);
            this.idMsg = 2;
            break;
        case 0:
            $('<p>', {
                class: 'combatText',
                id: `${this.idMsg}`
            }).appendTo('#combatLog');
            $(`#${this.idMsg}`).append(`Unsheathe your weapons...`);
            this.idMsg = 1;
        break;
        default:
            this.idMsg = 0;
    }
}
```

**The desired behavior would be:**

- I call the method **`startTimer()`**
- It calls **`combatStartLog()`** as an interval
- Each interval the property **`idMsg`** of the object falls into the corresponding case
- *`case '3'`* clears the interval and breaks the loop.

**What actually happens:**

- I don't know why in the first interval **`idMsg`** is instantiated as `undefined` even though its initial value is set in the constructor:

The constuctor

```
constructor(){
    this.idMsg = 0;
    this.timerInterval;
}
```

- I 'fixed' the problem above adding a default case with the code `this.idMsg = 0;` and when it gets to **case 3**, **idMsg** is set to **0** but the interval is never cleared and the loop goes on and on and on forever.

Comment: could you provide a sample app?

Comment: `console.log(this.idMsg);` needs to be inside the ***switch statement case's***. To fix undefined in beginning.

Comment: When `setInterval` is called. The context of `this` is different. Use an arrow function or `bind(this)`. I had this very same issue not an hour ago.

Comment: Another way is to just use `this.timerInterval = setInterval(() => this.combatStartLog(), 2000);`. The arrow function has no `this`, so it is not ambiguous as to what this refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By passing in the function to the setInterval function, when it is invoked, the 'this' variable loses context. So you need to make sure to bind 'this' of combatStartLog to the instance of CombatLog object:

```
class CombatLog {
constructor(){
this.idMsg = 0;
this.timerInterval;
this.combatStartLog = this.combatStartLog.bind(this);}}
```

When you call new CombatLog(), it calls the constructor function with 'this' as the new object being instantiated. By reassigning combatStartLog to combarStartLog bound to the new object, 'this' inside combatStartLog refers to the newly instantiated object.

Comment: When I call `combatStartLog()` as an interval, does it instantiate an new `CombatLog()` object in each interval? if that's the case, could it be a solution to call `combatStartLog()` directly using the name of a `CombatLog()` object I know it will be created?

Comment: No you first instantiate CombatLog by doing let combatLog = new CombatLog() and invoke startTimer function by calling combatLog.startTimer (). startTimer function will pass combatStartLog function to setInterval function. 'this' variable in combatStartLog references the new CombatLog object (combatLog).